# npm ERR! code HPE_UNEXPECTED_CONTENT_LENGTH

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

whenever doing npm install
I get npm ERR! code HPE_UNEXPECTED_CONTENT_LENGTH at the very beginning.

I am trying to get the source code from https://github.com/elastic/kibana
and then in the same path I am running `npm install` and I get this error

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code HPE_UNEXPECTED_CONTENT_LENGTH

npm ERR! Parse Error
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

I am not sure, what exactly is happening but npm install starts and after 30 - 40 secs it just throws this error.

Comment: Do you use a proxy or any other software that may be manipulating your traffic?

Comment: `: sill mapToRegistry uri http://npm.corp.****.com/****`  is taking long time and then I get the above error.

This is happening for all the dependencies @mscdex

Comment: So you're not using the "main" npm registry, but a third party registry?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a problem with your internal registry.
Try this:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```